# How to create PDF with header / footer using IO.popen and wkhtmltopdf in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I want to create PDF file using `IO.popen` command with `wkhtmltopdf`. I successfully create pdf file using `wkhtmltopdf` command using below code:

```
IO.popen('wkhtmltopdf '+ source_url.to_s + ' ' + Rails.root.to_s + '/app/assets/pdfs/' + file_to_download) do
end
```

But i want to create PDF with header and footer using same code. I am not finding this solutions please send me if any one have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is option **--header-html & --footer-html** to provide html header externally with your command

1) html file

```
wkhtmltopdf http://domain.com/pagetopdf.html --footer-html "footer.html" /path/to/folder/test.pdf
```

2) You can also pass text into footer & header as below

```
wkhtmltopdf http://domain.com/pagetopdf.html --footer-center "Hello Footer" /path/to/folder/test.pdf
```

There are so many other options to use see this [link](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html)